# Subdomain on Subnet B takes long time to handel Domain Queries to Parent Domain in Subnet A

Tags: windows, ipsec

we're using Active Directory with one domain and one subdomain.
The Subdomain is for "seperated" servers, which should be not accessible to our internal (parent) domain. This Servers are located on a specific subnet with a Subdomain Controller in it.

The two Subnets allow Communication between the Domain Controllres via IPSec so we can administrate the subdomain on our internal network.
dcdiag/repadmin show no errors.

We also use administrative accounts which should have access to the subdomain. This works fine, if we setup the group and members within the internal subnet/on the subdomain dc.

One problem we encounter, is a long time when the following happens:

An Administrator on Subdomain Member Server tries to add an user from the Parent Domain A. The resolution of the username takes a LONG time and fails often. The Member Server can contact the Subdomain DC (also GC), but cannot contact directly an Parent Domain DC (because it's located on another subnet).
IF we try to add an user multiple times, it works after the third/fourth try, but it's real timeconsumung to wait 5-10 minutes to add ONE user to an group.

My Question:
Is there an possibility to "proxy" the query for the parent domain via the subdomain DC? 
Can IPSec be an option (subdomain DC <-> Parent Domain DC communicate via IPSec) for member servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - i solved it with an ipsec tunnel.

I created an GPO for internal/external DC and defined an Server-to-Server IPSec Connection to each DC/Member Server on the Subdomain. 
Now it works without any slowdowns.